# How to sort data according to sectors and subsectors?

Tags: r, sorting

I would like to sort the data `x` (here: 1:12) according to the sectors `sec` and subsectors `ssec`. Below is an example showing how this can be done. The questions is whether this can be done more elegantly (maybe with a base-R function/not using additional packages)?

```
## Data
set.seed(17)
(sec <- sample(rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 4))) # 3 sectors
(ssec <- rep(sample(1:4, 12, replace = TRUE))) # 4 subsectors
x <- 1:12 # data to sort according to increasing sectors and subsectors

## Sort according to sectors
ord <- order(sec)
x. <- x[ord]
sec. <- sec[ord]
ssec. <- ssec[ord]

## Sort according to subsectors
usec. <- unique(sec.)
x.. <- x.
ssec.. <- ssec.
for(grp in usec.) {
    ii <- sec. == grp # indices of components in that sector
    ord. <- order(ssec.[ii])
    x..[ii] <- x.[ii][ord.]
    ssec..[ii] <- ssec.[ii][ord.]
}

## Result
x..
sec.
ssec..
```

Comment: You can pass multiple variables to sort by to `order()` function. for example. `x[order(sec, ssec)]`, is this what you need?

Comment: *Argh*, true... Very good, thanks! I think I used that some years ago and then forgot... had the feeling that there was a more elegant solution :-) Thanks again.

Comment: @Psidom, why not make that an official answer?

Comment: @gung I'll try. Even though I know it works, takes some effort to illustrate.

Comment: just use a `stopifnot(all(x[order(sec, ssec)] == x..))`. Shows they are equal (here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `order` function from `base` R also accepts multiple arguments. From `?order`:

> `order` returns a permutation which rearranges its first argument into
>   ascending or descending order, breaking ties by further arguments.

To demonstrate, we can check how `order(sec, ssec)` sort the sector and subsector

Here is the original `sec` and `ssec`:

```
sec
 [1] "B" "C" "A" "B" "A" "B" "C" "C" "C" "A" "B" "A"
ssec
 [1] 3 1 3 2 1 2 4 1 3 2 1 4
```

After applying the ordered index, sec is sorted alphabetically and ssec is sorted within each sec, which means the index `order(sec, ssec)` is the sorting index expected:

```
sec[order(sec, ssec)]
 [1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "B" "C" "C" "C" "C"
ssec[order(sec, ssec)]
 [1] 1 2 3 4 1 2 2 3 1 1 3 4
```